# Any Physics software for Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 Beta 2.

As a Physics simulation software I tried STEP. But I was disappointed because I had frequent crashes with that thing.

Is there any good Physics simulation software for Ubuntu?

Comment: I am using step in 11.10 ,without any problem ,try step in final release of 12.04, and since it is a kde application ,install kde for better perfomence

Comment: Many simulation software directly/indirectly works with the support of programming language. So add the programming language of your choice and repost it.

Answer (score 3):

You could try [elmer](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/elmer) [image: Install elmer] which is available in the software-centre.

Answer (score 3):

you should probably take a look here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuScience/Physics

A list of available apps:

- [Cernlib](http://cernlib.web.cern.ch/cernlib/)
- [Geant3](http://wwwasd.web.cern.ch/wwwasd/geant/)
- [Lightspeed](http://lightspeed.sourceforge.net/)
- [CLHEP](http://wwwasd.web.cern.ch/wwwasd/lhc++/clhep/)
- [ELMER](http://www.csc.fi/elmer/index.phtml)
- [JaxoDraw](http://jaxodraw.sourceforge.net/)

and much more.

Personally I advise you to user `cernlib`. To install:

```
sudo apt-get install cernlib
```

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a lot of software available in ubuntu repo.
Some programming background is essential while choosing the one fits your need.

- C/C++ : **Octave** + **gnuplot** (Numerical analysis)
- python : **Blender**, i personally recommend this one. Download a latest version of this software from its official site. It has physics render engine. yet the learning curve is steep.here are some [videos](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=physics%20blender)

Comment: Press ctrl+alt+t copy and paste this command **sudo apt-cache search "physics simulation"** Choose the according to your need.

Answer (score 1):

If you are used to Matlab, you may use Octave to edit **m files**. You can perform many numerical analysis tasks with Octave or Python. Make sure you have the correct libraries when using Python for plotting and analysis. (e.g. **matplotlib**, etc.).

Comment: Neither compare Octave to Matlab. Some people don't know they can edit .m files with Octave.

Comment: Downvote retracted and upvoted after your edit made things more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [scilab](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/scilab) [image: Install scilab] which is available in the Ubuntu software-center.